# How to test a select option in salesforce

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a `Visualforce Page` with picklist created using `selectOption` but I am not sure, how can I test this?

```
public String leadStatus { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption>   getAvailableLeadStatusList(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Lead.Status.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple){
        options.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getValue()));        
    }
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the [`<apex:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) tag instead?

Comment: yes...that can work too and i have done the same in my other vf pages but i just wanted to learn how can we test this option also.

Comment: Do you need test class to cover this code?

Comment: I experimented myself and just creating instance of class and calling get method seems to have cover the code.    SMSController ctrl = new SMSController();
        ctrl.getAvailableLeadStatusList();      Is it correct way?

Comment: I also wanted to use assert statements...

Comment: pls find my ans well

Comment: Thanks Santanu...I like the idea of testing particular value instead of checking isNotnull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Apex` for this use case. As I mentioned in the comments, just use the [`<apex:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) tag.

If you're just writing this code as a learning exercise, test it like you would any other property. Call the getter. In this case I would be hesitant to assert on any specific values, because you do not want to commit to a specific configuration. But you can at least verify the collection is non-null and not empty.

```
static testMethod void testLeadStatusOptions()
{
    MyController controller = new MyController();
    
    Test.startTest();
        List<SelectOption> options = controller.getAvailableLeadStatusList();
    Test.stopTest();
    
    system.assertNotEquals(null, options, 'The collection should be instantiated');
    system.assert(!options.isEmpty(), 'The collection should be populated');
}
```

It is very important that you learn to write valuable assertions in your unit tests. Salesforce's own [technical library goes so far as to say](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct) (emphasis mine):

> Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.

Comment: Thanks Adrian..! FOr all the knowledge and assert statement

Answer (score 1):

I am extending @Adrian's answer here.

If you really want to test the execution of your code in your test class then change this method like this introducing `Test.isRunningTest()`:

```
public class clsPicklistEntry {
    public String leadStatus { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption>   getAvailableLeadStatusList(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Lead.Status.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        if(Test.isRunningTest()){
            options.add(new SelectOption('test', 'test'));
        }
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : ple){
            options.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getValue()));        
        }

        return options;
    }

}
```

And in the test class, you assert the value which you are pushing for testing.

```
@isTest
public class TestClsPicklistEntry {
     @isTest static void testLeadStatusOptions()
    {
        clsPicklistEntry controller = new clsPicklistEntry();

        Test.startTest();
            List<SelectOption> options = controller.getAvailableLeadStatusList();
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assertEquals(options.get(0).getValue(), 'test');

    }
}
```